# Microsoft Graph API , http request with header

Tags: java, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I was using this code earlier with GraphAPI version 5.75.0

```
 CustomRequest<String> request =                                                       
   new CustomRequest<>(String.format(sendMailUri, toEmail), getGraphServiceClient(),   
       List.of(new HeaderOption("Content-Type", "text/plain")), String.class);
```

request.post(encodedContent);

the sendMailUri is ${app.graphAPI.sendMailUri:[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%s/sendMail}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%s/sendMail%7D)

I need to migrate this to latest version 6.4.0 how to do that , I know HeaderOption is depreciated I tried doing a lot of stuff but it was not working, Please help me out,

Thanks in advance!!

Was tying to use this

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v6.md#use-of-requestinformation-in-place-of-baserequestt

Could not find a conclusive solution

Comment: You might wanted to post what you tried that didn't work. When using the RequestInformation class https://github.com/microsoft/kiota-java/blob/3486a8e097c5340a870a5d71b12f2770cfc2911c/components/abstractions/src/main/java/com/microsoft/kiota/RequestInformation.java#L33 you should be able to set it via the SetStreamContent or possibly setContentFromParsable when your passing in the Mime Body.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the samples in the documentation. Take a look at 1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/java?tutorial-step=6&tabs=aad and 2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java